# HVAC System Seems to Take too Long to Cool 1 Degree

Tags: hvac

My house was built with my AC evaporator and furnace up in the open-air attic. For some time now I have been suspicious that the system/air handler is drawing in air from the attic: it can take 30 mins (a long time?) to cool the air in house down one degree (or raise it in the winter).  Also, if the humidity is high outside and much lower (as I like it) inside, simply running the fan for 15-20 minutes will raise the rel humidity inside by several points.

But I have been confused because temp readings of air coming out of registers is about °F once system has been running and moved all of the hot air out of the ducts in the attic...that seems plenty cold to me.

One HVAC contractor suggested I take a temperature reading on the plenum before the filter/fan: when AC had been running for enough time (~20-25 mins) to change the inside temp from 80°F to 79°F, and with the attic temp reading at (98-99)°F, the lowest temp reading I got off any of plenum walls with a thermometer gun thing was ~90°F - this was the actual furnace plenum and not the add-on (silver-sided) plenums where main return duct was attached.  Even the plenums after the evaporator that feed the ducts that run to ceiling air registers were at same temp as attic (98-99).

Does any (all?) of this provide cause for concern?  And if so, what is most likely cause or culprit?

Comment: I think what needs to be done is an actual visual inspection of the air handler and ductwork.  Looking for open leaks .  If running the fan raises the humidity so fast it suggests that there is an intake leak drawing in humid air from the attic.

Comment: 1 degree F is too fidgety a measurement, especially if it's the first degree F.   I would suggest setting up a logger and looking at change in the midrange.  However, checking that the system is not leaking is an easy 'walk-around' for the contractor. *Who will want to do that in the MORNING.*

Comment: 30 mins to drop one degree isn't abnormal, especially if it's really hot outside. It's on the slower end, but doesn't raise a huge flag. Try cleaning the air filter. AC is designed/spec'd to maintain a temp, it's not great at lowering them.

Answer (score 0):

Your contractor wants you to measure the air temperature immediately before and after the AC system. If you have an instant-read kitchen/barbecue thermometer, that will be good enough. Just stick it right through the duct and in to the air stream. Once you have your readings, tape over the holes with (wait for it...) duct tape!

If the difference between the two temperature readings (aka the temperature drop) is less than 25-30 degree F, then the problem is with the AC system itself.

Comment: note that non-contact IR thermometers don't like to read temps off of shiny surfaces, like ducting or foil.